# Logical expression to English

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, logic-translation

I have been working on logical expressions for a bit, I am still very much a beginner, I stumbled upon this question today and attempted to solve it, unfortunately, I am not too sure whats going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated .

The question

```
P(x) be the predicate "x is a Knight"
Q(x) be the predicate "x is a Wizard"
R(x) be the predicate "x likes archery"
The universe of discourse is all people

a. ∃ (() ∧ ¬() ∧ ())
b. ∀ (() ∧ ¬() ∧ ())
c. ∀ (() → ())
```

What i have so far

```
A)  At least on of the people is a knight and not a wizard and likes archery
B)  Living amongst people is a knight and not a wizard and likes archery
C)  If living amongst all people is a knight then they like archery
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two answers are incorrect. A correct solution is the following one:

```
B) Every living people is a knight, not a wizard, and likes archery.
C) Every living person which is a knight, also likes archery.
```

They can also be rephrased as:

```
B) Every living person is a knight who likes archery, and there are no wizards.
C) Every living knight likes archery.
```

Comment: Why did you guys change "all people" to "living people"?

Comment: @Student I just assumed that the universe in question was in fact "all living people" by looking at the answers proposed in the OP.